# sqlite query works on android 4.0.3, but crashes on 2.2

Tags: android

I have a query like this :

```
Cursor c = bdd.query(db.TABLE_TorrentDownload, new String[] {db.COL_ID, db.COL_INFOHASH, db.COL_TorrentName,db.COL_Progress,db.COL_Peers,db.COL_dl,db.COL_ul,db.COL_State,db.COL_FolderPath,db.COL_Selected}, db.COL_State + " LIKE '3' OR " + db.COL_State +  " LIKE '7'", null, null, null, null,null);
```

The query works on 4.0.3, but it crashes on the android 2.2 emulator. It gives me a sqliteException : no such column Selected

Any ideas why it crashes on 2.2?

**UPDATE 1**

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Selected: , while compiling: SELECT id, Info_Hash, TorrentName, Progress, Peers, dl, ul, State, Selected, FolderPath FROM tblTorrentDownload WHERE State LIKE '3' OR State LIKE '7'

Comment: what is bdd in you code

Comment: bdd = dbSQLite.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: Can you post the complete logcat and some code where the error is occuring. That will help to  debug the problem.

Comment: see my update, the stacktrace is null so i posted the detailmessage

Comment: Without the code, its impossible to debug, As an alternative, you can try using the rawQuery() method of getWritableDatabase(), instead of query() method.

Comment: emulator is not that good for Database practice... if you are using Database better to go for a real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uninstalling and re-installing the application on emulator 2.2. If you made any changes to database they are not reflected on the already running application because the `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)`(where you must have put your create query) doesn't get called. Clearing the data will also do the trick so will uninstalling and re installing the application.

Comment: Thanks, I had to update the database version since i added the column Selected.

Comment: You are welcome. Also check out the use of database version. It will come in play to update db structure after you have deployed the application. Note: Do not increase the database version during development